# Excel IFERROR display blank instead of 0

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

I have a requestform!B3 that works perfectly, however I want the cell that is pulling the data from B3 to start off blank or when there is no information in B3 to be blank.

I thought an IFERROR would work, see below, but it still displays the 0.
Please advise

=IFERROR(RequestForm!B3,"")

Comment: It will if `RequestForm!B3` is an error, but if it is 0 or blank then it is not an error.  Try `=IF(RequestForm!B3=0,"",RequestForm!B3)`

Comment: Dirty, that is awesome, thanks it works